# Unable to use variables for artifact name in gitab-ci.yml

Tags: windows, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have read GitLab's [Use CI/CD Variables to Define Artifact Name](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#use-cicd-variables-to-define-the-artifacts-name) documentation and examples.
In the following excerpt of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, I try to replicate their powershell example:

```
artifacts:
  name: "$env:CI_JOB_STAGE-$env:CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  expire_in: 1 week
  paths:
    - My\Hardcoded\Path\*
```

But when I download the artifact, it's named: `_env_CI_JOB_STAGE-_env_CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.zip`.  I wanted to use a variable for my artifact path, but that didn't work either, so I was forced to hardcode it.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm familiar with the open GitLab issue: [Artifacts Filename Cannot Be Set with Dynamic Variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1664), and I would eventually like to put a date & timestamp in the artifact name, but first I'd just like to get any variable working.

I'm using GitLab v15.1.1-ee.  My runner is v15.1.1, installed in Windows and uses a shell executor in powershell.

Comment: GitLab is not PowerShell, you don't need the `env:` prefix. `"$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"` should do

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen in my runner’s config.toml, my executor=“powershell”.  I also tested the other examples from the doc, including your suggestion, but it did not work.

Comment: correction: in my `config.toml` I have `executor = "shell"` and `shell = "powershell"`

Comment: This is most likely a bug in GitLab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/29141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Ville Laurikari's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869167/unable-to-use-variables-for-artifact-name-in-gitab-ci-yml?noredirect=1#comment128759666_72869167), it appears this was a bug affecting v15.1.1.  Today, I noticed that our GitLab instance was upgraded to v15.1.2-ee, and I replaced my runner with v15.1.0.  The variables now work as documented.